Op-amp voltage follower basic understanding
First of all following experiment with a simulation:

I have a basic question to the voltage follower. Normally a voltage follower is constructed the way of the top circuit in the image. And this behaviour makes sense to me. The op-amp will get the Vout to the level of Vin and since the feedback is on the inverting input, Vout == Vin.
Now on the bottom I was expecting the output to be -5V for the same logic.
What am I getting wrong?
Thank you!

Can you be more specific on (1) why you expect that, because you (2) don't mention what is your current understanding so we can't answer what's incorrect about it.


Now on the bottom I was expecting the output to be -5V for the same logic.

What you are getting wrong is that the second circuit is not an inverting amplifier as you seem to think. The upper circuit uses negative feedback to correct any tendency of the output to deviate from the input.
The lower circuit has positive feedback. This will amplify any deviation from the input voltage and make it worse.

In the bottom one, suppose the output (and therefore the non-inverting input) is at 5V. If the inverting input is at 5.01 then the output will change from 5V to the gain 'A' times -0.01V (the differential input voltage). If A is 1,000 (a very low gain, but bear with me) then the output will try to go to -10V. That will cause the non-inverting input go to -10V and now the differential input voltage is -10.01V and the output will try to go to -10,010 volts. It will limit near the supply rails, but it will go to (say) -14V with +/-15V supplies and stay there. It could also go to +14V depending on how exactly it started up.
This is what we call "positive feedback" and is the opposite of what we usually want in an op-amp (we do want it- a bit of it- in comparators, quite often).
If you want a -5V output, the appropriate configuration is more like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here we still have negative feedback, but when the inputs are driven equal the output voltage is (ideally) -5V. Note that you also have to have power supplies that are high enough. You can't get -5V from an op-amp powered from +10/0.
Also, unlike the voltage follower, the accuracy of the output depends on the resistor ratio (as well as the usually small imperfections in the op-amp). A general-purpose inexpensive op-amp might have a voltage follower DC accuracy of a few mV. If the resistors differ by 1% (one is high by 0.5% and the other low by 0.5%) then the -5V output will be off by 50mV. Worst-case with 1% resistors would thus be more than 100mV error.

understand please, that my question aims only for understanding of the OP-Amp not really in building anything. Why should under Ideal conditions the output still be positive? This is what I am simulating. Your explanation of the positive feedback is right, but still this does not answer why the output is positive. As for my perspective U diff is +5V so the V+ should be -5V?

As I said it could be positive or negative for an ideal op-amp. If the output goes higher than 5V it will keep going more and more positive, ideally to infinity. If it goes lower than 5V it will keep going more and more negative, ideally to minus infinity. The output of the op-amp is A$\cdot$((V+)-(V-)) and for an ideal op-amp A->$\infty$

You need to understand the difference between positive and negative feedback.  They are not mirror images of each other.

Philosophy of NFB circuits
The op-amp voltage follower is the most basic negative feedback circuit. Therefore, you need to understand the concept of this circuit and how it is implemented.
Generally speaking, the idea of a negative feedback follower is to produce an output quantity Y that is a copy of the input quantity X. To achieve this, Y is compared to X by subtracting it and adjusting it so that the difference is equal to zero. As a result, Y = X.
Thus, a voltage follower consists of two devices: a subtracting/summing device and an inverting/noninverting amplifier. In this case, the subtracting/summing device and the amplifier have different signs (polarities). Therefore, the feedback loop inverts the signal (there is a negative feedback).
NFB follower
Conceptual circuit: The combination of a subtractor SUB and a non-inverting amplifier A forms a follower.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Series voltage subtractor: To realize this circuit, we simply connect the input and output voltage sources in series but with opposite polarities. The voltage difference we get is a "floating" voltage, meaning it is not referenced to ground.

simulate this circuit
Non-inverting follower: Therefore, we need an (op-amp) amplifier that can handle this type of (differential) input.

simulate this circuit
NFB inverter
We have another way to go about this.
Conceptual circuit: The combination of a summer SUM and an inverting amplifier -A forms an inverter.

simulate this circuit
Parallel voltage summer: To realize this circuit, we connect the input and output voltage sources with the same polarities in parallel through resistors. Now the voltage difference dV is referenced to ground...

simulate this circuit
Inverting follower: ... so the amplifier can be with single-ended input.

simulate this circuit
Philosophy of PFB circuits
Positive feedback circuits exhibit more complex behavior compared to those with negative feedback. The phenomenon of hysteresis comes into play, requiring the addition of a voltage divider to the positive feedback loop. Given the length of my answer, I will conclude with the concept of current. I am happy to provide further explanations if needed.
In the case if positive feedback, the subtracting/summing device and the amplifier have the same signs (polarities). Therefore, the feedback loop does not invert the signal (there is a positive feedback).
PFB inverting comparator
Conceptual circuit: The combination of a subtractor SUB and an inverting amplifier A forms an inverting comparator with hysteresis (inverting Schmitt trugger).

simulate this circuit
Series voltage subtractor

simulate this circuit
Op-amp inverting comparator

simulate this circuit
PFB non-inverting comparator
Conceptual circuit: The combination of a summer SUM and a non-inverting  amplifier A forms a non-inverting comparator with hysteresis (non-inverting Schmitt trugger).

simulate this circuit
Parallel voltage subtractor

simulate this circuit
Op-amp non-inverting comparator

simulate this circuit
Conclusions

A voltage follower is a circuit with negative feedback that has two variations: non-inverting and inverting.

If the inputs of an op-amp are swapped, positive feedback circuits are obtained.

Their output voltage is almost equal to the supply rail voltage.

Its polarity depends not only on the current input voltage but also on the previous one.


